# How to Change Layout Params on pinch zoom in android?

Tags: android, layout, pinch

Hello Developers,
         i am having a relative layout and inside that having  web view so i want to integrate the pinch zoom and on pinch zoom i want to change the webview height and width parameters multiplied with the current scale factor  ,i tried a lot of similar question but i am not able to pinch the web view .
Please suggest me some suitable working examples.
Thanks in Advance